# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException when starting tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, java

How to solve it?? I installed Java 7 and this occured when starting tomcat which has my application. I think the problem is based on my application. (
Tomcat 7 run successfully before. I installed java 7 and uninstall java 6 after this installation problem occured)

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/m.apus]]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/m.apus]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/FinderException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    ... 21 more
```

- Edit

LifecycleException ocurred before I installed Java 7. I think this exception is not based on that. But I don't know why I encounter this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java EE libraries, there's files needed to support EJB.  You've got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the class that is in the library that implements Java EE specification. The file you you need is `javax.ejb.jar` from version 6 Java EE default reference implementation. Supply Java EE libraries with your Java web applications. Initially Tomcat has not support for EJB.

Comment: Tomcat 7 run successfully before. I installed java 7 and uninstall java 6 after this installation problem occured.

Comment: @kamal - If it ran successfully with a JDK 6 installation and didn't after you removed that JDK 6 installation, then there was something about *that particular installation*. I'm willing to bet that you downloaded Java EE JARs and stored them in your JDK (which is a bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 is not a (full) Java EE container. It is "just" a servlet/JSP server.

If you need EJBs, you'll need a full-fledged Java EE server such as [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) or [JBoss](https://www.jboss.org/jbossas)